# VB.Net - Extract from textbox

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I have a textbox with data.

```
"data": "100005337941637",
"data": "100004464150724",
etc..
```

I want just numbers("100005337941637").

My code is almost good for me, but not enough specified.

```
For Each m As Match In New Regex("\d+").Matches(TextBox1.Text)
            TextBox2.Text &= m.Value & Environment.NewLine
        Next
```

I can filter my numbers?
If my numbers 10-15 digit then it's okay, if not then it will be delete.

Example:
100005337941637 -okay
100004464150724- okay
1043434 - it's not okay

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nearly there, try `"[\d]{10,15}(?=[""])"`

This matches any amount of digits of a minimum length of 10, but no bigger than 15. Then finally checks the final digit in the pattern is followed by a quotation mark `"` as this means it's the last digit in the string.

Alternatively, you could modify something like this (not tested):

```
For Each xVar In Split(TextBox1.Text, vbCrLf)
   For i = 1 To Len(xVar)
      If IsNumeric(Mid(xVar, i, 1)) Then xStr = xStr & Mid(xVar, i, 1)
   Next i

   If Len(xVar) > 9 And Len(xVar) < 16 Then MsgBox(xVar.ToString)

   xStr = vbNullString

Next xVar
```

Comment: Aah, quotes in VB, might need to change `["]` to `[""]`

Comment: One more question if not problem. If I also have a text "link" data? How can I extract? Example: http://pastebin.com/fJh9nTqN

Comment: I would need to see exactly what it looks like within your data, but a generic pattern for catching a link might look something like `[a-z-]+(\.[a-z]{2,3}){1,2}[\/][\w&%-]+$`